# Installing APK from email attachment

Tags: android, email, apk

Whenever i send a .apk file via email as an attachment and then open the .apk-file in my phone from my email-account, i get a parsing error.
However if i put the .apk on my website and provide a URL to it, it works like a charm.

A bug? Just me? Am i doing it wrong?
Thanks

Comment: I got the same behavior. Which email-app do you use? Stock Mail? GMail? K9-Mail?

Comment: So its just not me :) I use GMail.
This is actually annoying me when i need to send out a demo-version to my friends and they can't get it installed from the attachment.

Comment: This is a good question but questions like this are even better for http://android.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That on new Android versions works very well, because, if the attachment is and apk then appear an install button. (on GMail native app)

But for older Android versions you will need and app like Email install 
this one : http://www.appbrain.com/app/email-installer/com.best.app.attachment

Comment: Google has now decided to prevent everyone from using APK via email - they artificially block *all* emails that contain a .APK attachment, and their help article says they will not fix this and will not allow anyone to disable it. Score -1 for anyone unlucky enough to have a gmail address.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue with **Android ICS (4.0.4)**. I would suggest, do not try to open the attachment `(.apk)` if the gmail account is configured in the device. Instead, Open your gmail account in the browser,open the email and now try to download the attachment. 
It worked for me :) Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I can install apps received from in my gmail account.  My exchange and pop mail accounts will not allow it.

FYI - If you have Astro File Browser make sure the 'Enable Browser Download' option is disabled.  It is a handy feature to allow download of any file type, but it interferes with gmail attachments.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to transfer and install is by emailing it.  When sending, set your text settings to Unicode text, if for some reason it gives you a parsing error when trying to install on your phone.  Astro or another of file browser app is useful for finding the file after you download it from email, just tried it and it worked fine.  The only errors came  when I used any other text setting in email besides Unicode. Unicode text and everything installed perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I started getting the error `Can't find app to open file` on Google's `Inbox` app when installing an `.apk` through it, but then I tried it in `Gmail`, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem when sending an apk from Mail on OSX but the same apk installed when sent from gmail.

> To investigate this issue, I saved the output from 'Show original' in
> gmail for the emails sent from gmail and Mail. I ran:
>
> ```
> diff fromGmail.txt fromMail.txt
> ```
>
> And noticed the following difference in the attachment Content-Types:
>
> from gmail:
>
> ```
> Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive;
> ```
>
> from Mail:
>
> ```
> Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
> ```
>
> I suspect this difference is the major culprit.

You can refer to my question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587328/apk-wont-install-some-of-the-time-over-email-from-mail-osx/33587354#33587354). My guess is that any mail client that sends apk attachments with the correct content-type would pass installation.